# Replace characters of a string matched by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in a situation to find the domain name of all valid URLs among a HTML page, replace these domain names with another domain name, but within the domain name, I need to do a 2nd replacement. For example, say the url `https://www.example.com/path/to/somewhere` is among the HTML page, I need to eventually transfer it into something like `www-example-com.another.domain/path/to/somewhere`.

I can do the first match and replace with the following code:

```
    const regex = new RegExp('(https?:\/\/([^:\/\n\"\'?]+))', 'g');

    txt = txt.replace(regex, "$1.another.domain");
```

but I have no idea how to do the second match and replace to replace the `.` into `-`. I wonder if there is any efficient way to finish this task. I tried to do something like the following but it does not work:

```
    const regex = new RegExp('(https?:\/\/([^:\/\n\"\'?]+))', 'g');

    txt = txt.replace(regex, "$1".replace(/'.'/g, '-') + ".another.domain");
```

Comment: You don't need regex for the char replacement. You know the char code. Remove the `/ /g` so it's just `'.'`

Comment: @JoelHager: What if 'somewhere' contains a dot?

Comment: It seemed as though every dot in your case was being switched with a -. Can you provide more contextual info about possible edge cases?

Comment: @JoelHager, there's no edge cases, I just want to replace all dots into dashes, and of course there are more than one dots. Following your first suggestion by removing the ```/ /g``` does not work, it does not even replace the first dot.

Comment: I saw your case, I think I know what you're looking for now. Have a look at my answer and see if that does what you want. It gives me the expected result, and you can declare new strings/domains at the top to have it automatically change. :)

Comment: @JoelHager, thank you, get the job done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [function version of `String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to have some more control over the specific replacements.

For example...

```js
const txt = 'URL is https://www.example.com/path/to/somewhere'

const newTxt = txt.replace(/(https?:\/\/)([\w.]+)/g, (_, scheme, domain) =>
  `${scheme}${domain.replace(/\./g, '-')}.another.domain`)

console.log(newTxt)
```

Here, `scheme` is the first capture group `(https?:\/\/)` and `domain` is the second `([\w.]+)`.

If you need a fancier *domain* matcher (as per your question), just substitute that part of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I think I know what you're looking for. I'll explain what it's doing.

You 2 capture groups: the one before *and* the one after the first `/`.

You're taking the first capture group, and converting the `.` to `-`

You're adding via string `.another.domain` and then you're appending the 2nd capture group on it afterward

```js
const address1 = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/somewhere';
const newDomain = "another.domain"

const pattern = /(https?:\/\/[^:\/\n\"\'?]+)(\/.*)/;

const matches = pattern.exec(address1);

const converted = matches[1].replace(/\./g, "-") + `.${newDomain}${matches[2]}`;
console.log(converted);
```